# iOS RestKit, mapping with dependency on other keys

Tags: ios, restkit

I have some unique data returned from my API that I would like to represent correctly in the models.

A sample response would look like this:

```
{
    'name' : 'Mr. John Smith',
    'preferred_format' : 'first_name_only'
}
```

The model has 3 properties: name, preferred name, and preferred format.
So the mapping should set

```
name = 'Mr. John Smith'
preferred_name = 'John'
preferred_format = enumPreferredFormatFirstOnly
```

Where enumPreferredFormatFirstOnly is a enumerated value. I know the json data is odd, and I know the model is odd, but I must follow these specs.

Can RestKit map the properties (name and preferred_format), while also setting the preferred_name property, which relies on the other two properties?

I was thinking of a custom value transformer for preferred_name with a nil key. But I need the transformed value of preferred_format first.

Answer (score 0):

No, that would basically be magic.

You should add custom setter methods for your 2 properties so you can convert them to the desired enum and then use the enum and full name to set the preferred name.

A transformer will be complex to use here as this isn't what they're for.

Comment: In RestKit's wiki they say "More realistic implementations of value transformers include ... and enumerated types". I will be trying a solution out soon.

Comment: But you aren't using to create the enum, you're using to combine 2 other values...